# Execute custom action on Install type/level

Tags: wix, wix3.7

We have an installer being built in WIX. The installation takes two different paths, one of which includes a service installation.

The service is written with Topshelf so we needed to use a custom action to install it. What we can not figure out how to do is only execute the custom action on a particular installation type or level.

```
<CustomAction Id="ConfigureInstallSyncClient" Property="InstallSyncClient" Value='"[InstallDirectory]Sync.Client.WindowsService.exe" install' Execute="immediate"/>
<CustomAction Id="InstallSyncClient" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>


<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="ConfigureInstallSyncClient" Before="StartServices">NOT (REMOVE ~= "ALL")</Custom>
  <Custom Action="InstallSyncClient" After="ConfigureInstallSyncClient">NOT (REMOVE ~= "ALL")</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Is what we are doing. It works when we want the service installed but fails when we aren't installing the service

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Feature` element in Custom action condition to ensure the custom action related files are installed or not.

For example if you listed the custom action related components under the feature named `Feature_InstallSyncClient` then your custom action should be like below.

```
<Custom Action="InstallSyncClient" After="ConfigureInstallSyncClient">NOT (REMOVE ~= "ALL") AND ( &Feature_InstallSyncClient = 3)</Custom>
```

Find more details regarding these conditions in [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Don't use Feature state in a Condition when Component state can be used instead.